# Android : Push data with notification

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, push

I am developing an application. The application is client server based.

The need of application is that:

1. I want to push data from server to device without web service, As like push notification. I want to push data which are more in size as compare to the notification and the data may be text, xml, json, .png, .jpg any thing.

   I had tried the push notification demo from [This Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)
2. Whenever there is extra data added to the server, only that data should push from server to device with notification. When user click on the notification data gets display from device, don't want to fetch data after click on the notification with web server.

Please suggest me i am in middle of my application.

So please suggest me what steps should I follow to achieve this task. Guide me with your valuable knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need of application is that:

```
1. I want to push data from server to device without web service, As like push notification. I want to push data which are more in size as compare to the notification and the data may be text, xml, json, .png, .jpg any thing.

2. Whenever there is extra data added to the server, only that data should push from server to device with notification. When user click on the notification data gets display from device, don't want to fetch data after click on the notification with web server.
```

You can push data in the form of payload as we can send message from server to device. But the maximum size of data we can send is 4KB.

You just check following code as :

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Message received", System.currentTimeMillis());
    // Hide the notification after its selected
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    //adding LED lights to notification
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessageReceivedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("payload", payload);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Message", "New message received", pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

May this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

check this [link](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin#manual-installation-for-android).

Note: Make sure you use GCM's "server key" instead of "android key" for "API key".

Comment: This link is for push notification. But i want to push data and images or files with notification.

Comment: 1.you can add data in the request body from your 3rd party server.
2.For image you can send image link or base64 format of the image.
Note : GCM only supports 4kb of data to be sent in notification. Also send the request body in JSON structure.

You can access this data in the event callback "onNotificationGCM", in "Message" switch-case tag.
The received data is in JSON format and you can access it as "e.payload.your_json_data_key".

Comment: instead of ruby script you can create your server request using chrome's advanced rest client.